# How to perform feature selection on dataset with categorical and numerical features?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection, rfe

I am working on a dataset with 30 columns (29 numerical, 1 non-ordinal categorical). I hot-encoded the categorical feature and reached at 35 columns.
To improve training efficiency, I want to perform feature selection on my dataset. However , I am confused with how to handle a dataset with categorical and numerical features combined.

1. I read that it is not reasonable to apply PCA on dummies given they
   are discrete. Is it reasonable to apply PCA first on numerical
   features then concatenate them with dummies?
2. I tried to implement
   recursive feature elemination with cross-validation (RFECV) to the
   entire feature space. But I don't think it is reasonable to remove
   some but not all dummy features given they are generated out of one
   category.

Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a better question for [datascience.se] since it relates to theory  and best practice rather than programming or coding

Comment: How about you give correlation analysis a try first? If your data is in a dataframe df, apply CM = df.corr() and then analyze abs(CM['target'].values). The smallest values should show you which features are irrelevant to your target.